# Using Bash to add a line as a new MySql entry

Tags: mysql, bash

is there a way for me to be able to add each line from a text file to a mysql database where each line is given a new ID?
The text file is just a list of numbers and there's a new line for every new entry like this

```
45
33
55
67
41
```

I want to do it in bash but not sure how to go about this. My skill in bash is limited though.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create simple MySQL INSERT statements (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) which you may want to review before importing into the database, the following approach might be helpful:

```
cat ids.txt | awk '{print "INSERT INTO TABLE mytable (myfield) VALUES ("$1");"}' > myinserts.sql
```

If that is what you expected, you can execute the statements (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-batch-commands.html):

```
mysql mydb < myinserts.sql
```

Of course you can do this in one step too without creating a temporary file:

```
cat ids.txt | awk '{print "INSERT INTO TABLE mytable (myfield) VALUES ("$1");"}' | mysql mydb
```

It is not as efficient as the comment from juergen d, but is more flexible if you want to have more control over the generated INSERT statements.